# leaflet openstreetmaps renders partially in google chrome

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am using leaflet and openstreetmaps with Wicket (java web mvc). The maps renders fine on Firefox and IE. On google chrome if my div height is 600 the map is visible like a bar on the top 200 px the bottom 400 px is grayed. There are no errors in the browser console. If I drag the map down the map renders the whole 600 px. If I drag the map up the map is grayed the whole 600px.

I cannot really post the code as it is embedded in many js files and we use canvas to draw on the map so there is not a small piece of code that I can put it here.

if you have had similar issue, please let me know how you fixed it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance the map is not displayed (in a tab / `display: none` / whatever) at initialization? What happens if you resize your browser window once the issue is visible?

Comment: When I resize it renders fine. but only once than its back to square one. I did not understand you comment about (tab / display: none / whatever) The map does show up but as a small strip instead of occupying the whole div

Comment: Sorry I meant the map container. See if this post applies to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658773/leaftlet-on-ionic-tabs-app-shows-only-first-tile

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reloading the page. I used a cookie to set a flag. when the page loads for the first time, I set the cookie and reload. If the cookie is set then do not reload any more.

I do this only if the browser is chrome not otherwise. So far its a little annoying but atleast can see the maps.